How to use a MultiResponse technique in an Azure Functions 4.x (.NET 8) with multiple bindings in C# code?
.NET 8.0.403, Functions 4.0.6280
Using the MultiResponse technique from Microsoft, I get

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead

The error has occurred in two separate VS Code environments on both Windows and MacOS. It errors when uploaded to Azure too.
I've read the 'work-around' but would rather fix the code.
Here's what I tried:
The offending line was response.WriteString(message); so I changed it to await response.WriteStringAsync(message); and changed the function...
FROM:
[Function("HttpExample")]
public static MultiResponse Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{...}

to:
[Function("HttpExample")]
public static async Task<MultiResponse> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    FunctionContext executionContext)
{...}

That worked... but next I wanted to add an input binding. So I changed it again to:
[Function("HttpExample")]
public static async Task<MultiResponse> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    [CosmosDBInput(
         databaseName: "my-database",
         containerName: "my-container",
         Id = "f3ac2913-85c4-4066-a5e9-1c68d1fd33e9",
         PartitionKey = "f3ac2913-85c4-4066-a5e9-1c68d1fd33e9",
         Connection = "CosmosDbConnectionSetting")] MyDocument inputDocument,
         FunctionContext executionContext)
{...}

That threw the following error:
[2024-10-23T20:57:51.153Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpExample' (Failed, Id=487a5679-088d-4c2d-b804-f6415fdb99b2, Duration=1094ms)
[2024-10-23T20:57:51.153Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpExample. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2024-10-23T20:57:51.153Z] Exception: IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
[2024-10-23T20:57:51.153Z] Object name: 'Collection'.
[2024-10-23T20:57:51.153Z] Stack:    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ThrowContextDisposed()
[2024-10-23T20:57:51.153Z]    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ContextDisposed()

From what I can tell it means the HttpContext is getting disposed of too early and my reading leads me to believe a non-static class/function will fix this even though it's not great for this scenario.
So I changed the parent class and the function to:
[Function("HttpExample")]
public async Task<MultiResponse> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
    [CosmosDBInput(
         databaseName: "my-database",
         containerName: "my-container",
         Id = "f3ac2913-85c4-4066-a5e9-1c68d1fd33e9",
         PartitionKey = "f3ac2913-85c4-4066-a5e9-1c68d1fd33e9",
         Connection = "CosmosDbConnectionSetting")] MyDocument inputDocument,
         FunctionContext executionContext)
{...}

But that throws the same error. I'm about ready to give up and use the Cosmos DB SDK instead of bindings. Not what I wanted to do as this project is to help me understand and implement Azure Functions.
Final questions:

Has anyone else experienced the initial error with the example from Microsoft?
Is there an easier way to apply input bindings with the MultiResponse technique?


Do you wish to have both input and output binding in a single function or an input binding only? @Matt

MultiResponse is being used for output binding wherein we are writing to cosmos DB, but in case of input binding, we will retrieve the document from cosmos DB. So why do you want to use MultiResponse for input binding? You can add input binding without MultiResponse too


Exception: IFeatureCollection has been disposed. Object name: 'Collection'. Stack:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences1.ThrowContextDisposed()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FeatureReferences`1.ContextDisposed()


In order to get rid of this error and execute your function successfully replace ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() with ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults() in program.cs file and also remove the packages associated to it. I believe the error is coming from ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(). You need to have given packages in your .csproj file.

using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_79120285</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="2.0.0-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.0.0-preview2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="4.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="2.0.0-preview2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


If you want to integrate ASP .NET Core in your function, then use ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication() in your code or else go for ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults().

I have the given code wherein I am reading documents from container using input binding and writing to another container using output binding.


using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using System.Net;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public class HttpExample
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HttpExample> logger;

        public HttpExample(ILogger<HttpExample> _logger)
        {
            logger = _logger;
        }

        [Function("HttpExample")]
        public async Task<MultiResponse> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        [CosmosDBInput(
            databaseName: "my-database",
            containerName: "my-container",
            Id = "{query.id}", 
            PartitionKey = "{query.partitionKey}",
            Connection = "CosmosDbConnectionSetting")] MyDocument inputDocument,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            var logger = executionContext.GetLogger("HttpExample");
            logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var message = inputDocument != null 
                ? $"Document found: {inputDocument.message}"
                : "No document found.";

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            await response.WriteStringAsync(message);

            return new MultiResponse()
            {
                Document = new MyDocument
                {
                    id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    message = message
                },
                HttpResponse = response
            };
        }
    }

    public class MultiResponse
    {
        [CosmosDBOutput("my-database", "OutputBindingContainer",
            Connection = "CosmosDbConnectionSetting", CreateIfNotExists = true)]
        public MyDocument? Document { get; set; }
        public HttpResponseData? HttpResponse { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyDocument
    {
        public string? id { get; set; }
        public string? message { get; set; }
    }
}


By making above mentioned changes, you can get the expected response.

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-10-24T07:45:58.348Z] Found C:\Users\******\79120285.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-10-24T07:46:00.474Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        HttpExample: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpExample

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-10-24T07:46:05.426Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000D2022A4'.
[2024-10-24T07:46:10.334Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpExample' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=c2bbb183-b62e-4301-9253-d275ad061c21)
[2024-10-24T07:46:14.671Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-10-24T07:46:19.162Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpExample' (Succeeded, Id=c2bbb183-b62e-4301-9253-d275ad061c21, Duration=8847ms)



I'm gobsmacked. Thank you Ikhtesam. I spent hours researching this and nothing led me to your suggestion. I made the changes to Program.cs and the .csproj file and the disposal error did not occur, however, I'm now getting
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpExample. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'PartitionKey').
It's extremely odd since your code and mine are nearly identical and this worked yesterday. CosmosDBOutput shouldn't require a PartitionKey in this instance.

You need to pass partition key for input binding

It's there for the input and works without error. The error comes on output which makes no sense. The output should not require a PartitionKey.

Yes, output binding only requires database name and container name

Do you have CreateIfNotExists = true in output binding? I have it

Yes. I had CreateIfNotExists = true included in my version. To baseline, I copied your provided .csproj (already identical minus comments), Program.cs (same code), and HttpExample.cs. Same error: System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpExample. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'PartitionKey').

The input binding works fine. I'm able to add a breakpoint and watch the expected value populate from the Cosmos DB item. It's the response that appears to break.
